# Not able to fetch key and value from nested JSON data in IONIC

Tags: json, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I face a problem now that I am not able to fetch key and value from nested JSON data.Please help me I am doing any wrong.

```
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" type="item-text-wrap" nav-transition="android" ng-repeat="data in hrINPROCandidateList | filter:search">
    <p class="small-text blue-text ">{{data.cfname}}</p>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.note_detail_fields track by $index">
      <div class="col field">{{key}}</div>
      <div class="col field-info">{{value}}</div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
"responseToken": 1,
"list": [
    {
        "candidate_id": "4",
        "note_detail_fields": "{\"link\":\"View Interview Details\",\"job_title\":\"Sopra Executive\",\"Candidate\":\"Mark Ashton\",\"Interview_Type\":\"First Interview\",\"\":\"\",\"Duration\":\"30 minutes\",\"Date\":\"Wednesday, 23<sup>rd<\\/sup> November 2016\",\"Time\":\"09:00 to 09:30\",\"Location\":\"london\"}",
        "cfname": "Idris",
        "clname": "Alba"
    },
    {
        "candidate_id": "506",
        "note_detail_fields": null,
        "cfname": null,
        "clname": null
    },
    {
        "candidate_id": "32",
        "note_detail_fields": "{\"link\":\"View Shared Job\",\"job_title\":\"Manager\",\"Location\":\"London, United Kingdom\",\"Package\":\"800 - 850 per day GBP\"}",
        "cfname": "Sajal",
        "clname": "Agarwal"
    }
],
"totalCount": "4",
"success": 1,
"status": null
}
```

View data in app

[image: View data in app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re trying to loop through a string instead of an array, create a filter that parse the json contained in `data.note_detail_fields`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.note_detail_fields | fromJson track by $index">
  <div class="col field">{{key}}</div>
  <div class="col field-info">{{value}}</div>
</div>


app.filter('fromJson',function(){
    return function(input){ return angular.fromJson(input); }
})
```